# Simply starred language. $\left\{(ab)^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ it is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

[image]

I have many doubts with this.
First: In the definition, let $A=\left\{x\right\}$ one-letter alphabet. Then $A^{\ast}$ is simply starred?

Second: In the definition, I know that $\left\{a^nb^n: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is not regular (because of the Pumping lemma) but $\left\{a^nb ^n: n \in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is  it simply starred anyway?

On the other hand, I know that if $r$ regular expression, then $L(r)$ is regular and so $(L(r))^{\ast}$ is regular.  But if we start from $A=\left\{ab\right\}$ with $ab$ string, then 
$L(ab)$ is regular so $(L(ab))^{\ast}$ is regular and $(L(ab))^{\ast}=\left\{ab\right\}^{\ast}=\left\{(ab)^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is not regular, a contradiction. What is wrong?

pd:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $x^*$ is simply starred (for a fixed string $x$) since all star operations in the expression are applied directly to a single string. So is $(ab)^*$ for the same reason. Some more examples (assuming $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are strings or characters):

- $a^*b^*c^*$ is simply starred.
- $a(bc)^*d + efg^*$ is simply starred.
- $a(b + c)d + e + fg$ is simply starred.
- $(a + b)^*$ is not simply starred.
- $(a^*b^*)^*$ is not simply starred.

Note, however, that the language of a regular expression which is not simply starred may actually be simply starred. This is because a language may be expressed by a different regular expression which is simply starred. For instance, $(a^*)^*$ is not simply starred, but its language is, since $L((a^*)^*) = L(a^*)$.

You are correct in stating that $\{a^nb^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular. It is not simply starred because by definition, the term "simply starred" is used to describe regular languages.

Your last statement claims that $\{(ab)^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular, when in fact it is. Are you perhaps confusing $(ab)^n$ with $a^nb^n$ here? They mean very different things.

Edit: I slightly misunderstood Definition 1.3.3; I have removed my bad example.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. It had confused me, but now I understand it.

On the other hand, is $\left\{x^2\right\}$ simply starred?

Comment: $\{x^2\}$ has no stars at all so any statement about it of the form "all star closures are $P$" is trivially true. Hence, yes it is.

Comment: Is it true that if $L_1$, $L_2$ are simply starred, so is the union $L_1\cup L_2$ and intersection $L_1\cap L_2$?
I ask this because I do not fully understand the definition of simply starred

Comment: I misunderstood the definition of simply starred at first, so I have now amended my answer to reflect the correct definition. Does it help clear things up?

Comment: I still do not understand the all well definition.

For example, the book gives the following example:
¿It is $(x^3\cup x^4)^{\ast}$ simply starred??
I ask, because the book gives it as an example of the above. That is, it is an example of a language simply starred and ${\ast}$-closed  but it can not be left as a single regular expression

Comment: That expression is not simply starred according to the above definition, as the language represented by $x^3 \cup x^4$ is a language containing more than one element. However, $L((x^3 \cup x^4)^*)$ is simply starred per Lemma 1.3.4.

Comment: But $(x^3\vee x^4)^{\ast}=(x^3\vee x^4)\cup x^{\ast}(x^6)$ and $(x^3\vee x^4)$ is simply starred (because is finite), $x^{\ast}$ is simply starred and $x^6$ is simply starred (because is finite) then union of simply starred  is simply starred,so $(x^3\vee x^4)\cup x^{\ast}(x^6)$ is simply starred, therefore $(x^3\vee x^4)^{\ast}$ is simply starred. It is correct?...

Comment: No. See the second paragraph of my answer. The regular expression $(x^3 \vee x^4)^*$ is not simply starred, yet $L((x^3 \vee x^4)^*) = L((x^3\vee x^4)\cup x^{\ast}(x^6))$ is, because $(x^3\vee x^4)\cup x^{\ast}(x^6)$ is simply starred. This is perfectly in line with the definition. A _language_ being simply starred does not mean every regular expression capable of representing it is simply starred. It just means that _some_ regular expression representing it is simply starred. So, you cannot conclude that $r$ is simply starred just because $L(r)$ is.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for asking so much, but the definition is hard for me. I asked the previous thing because in the second photo (which I just added) they say that $(x^3\vee x^4)^{\ast}=(x^3\vee x^4)\cup x^{\ast}(x^6)$...

Comment: No, it doesn't. It says that the languages of the two regular expressions are the same. Clearly they are different expressions. I demonstrated that $L((a^*)^*) = L(a^*)$ and yet only one of $(a^*)^*$ and $a^*$ is simply starred.

Comment: A doubt.
If $L$ is simply starred, and $L'\subset L$, then $ L'$ is simply starred?

Comment: Seems the chat room disappeared. In any case, the answer is no, as $L'$ need not be regular.